# how to copy input data from one file to another one? in java

Tags: java, string, methods, file-handling

I have a class called `CopyFile.java` that has a method with the name `copyingFile()` that takes in two strings-(String userInfo, String outputfile).
The first argument is for the user info filename and
the second argument is for the output filename. The user input data from the first text file is to be copied to the second file as output.
I was trying to do this but think I went off on the wrong road lol [here is an image of what I have so far which is probably all wrong

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should not do anything with that scanner and `user`, just write `line` to the new file.
Something like:[image]
I hope you also see why it's better to provide code as text and not as picture.
If linebreaks disappear (they probably will), add a `bufferedWriter.newLine();` into the loop, I did not try the code for obvious reasons.

EDIT: you should supply actual filenames when calling `copyFile()` (not just empty strings) and they should be different.